# iptables rules randomly change - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I have a simple set of iptables rules which start on boot a script in **/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/**:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

Similarly I have a script in **/etc/network/if-post-down.d/** to save my existing rules:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.downrules ]; then
   iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
fi
exit 0
```

Rules used to be saved and loaded properly until I installed **ExpressVPN**.

The software modifies my iptables rules each time I use it (which makes sense). But also sometimes (on random) when I haven't used it my rules get adjusted with some rules which include **xvpn** - so I assume it has to do with ExpressVPN. It's very annoying as it affects my connection and overall laptop performance.

My question is: how to disable firing these additional rules **(without uninstalling ExpressVPN)**. Any idea what can be starting them? I can see nothing obvious on startup or in /etc/network/ folders, nothing in cron either. Where else can I look for scripts that can be causing this ?